# http post request firebase cloud function

Tags: http, firebase, post, google-cloud-functions

I want to make post request and send data into body in firebase cloud function.
as default, it is get request or post request?

```
 var functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.tryfunction= functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // or it should be req.query 
});
```

how do I know and decide what the method it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just sharing simple code part. I'm using like this.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');


 exports.postmethod = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  if(request.method !== "POST"){
    response.send(405, 'HTTP Method ' +request.method+' not allowed');
    }

  response.send(request.body);
 });
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default.  The request method is whatever the client chose to send.

The `req` object in your callback is an express.js [Request](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) object.  Use the linked documentation, you can see that the request method can be found by using [req.method](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.method).

Comment: @AdirZoari check out my answer. I described how to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the HTTP method that your Firebase Function accepts you need to use Express API as you'd normally do in a standard Express app.

You can pass a full Express app to an HTTP function as the argument for `onRequest()`. This way you can use Express' own API to restrict your Firebase function to a specific method. Here's an example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Add middleware to authenticate requests or whatever you want here
app.use(myMiddleware);

// build multiple CRUD interfaces:
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.getById(req.params.id)));
app.post('/', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.create()));
app.put('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.update(req.params.id, req.body)));
app.delete('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.delete(req.params.id)));
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.list()));

// Expose Express API as a single Cloud Function:
exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Explanation of the above code:
We expose a Firebase function with endpoint `/widgets` with different handlers for different HTTP methods using Express' own API, e.g. `app.post(..)`, `app.get(..)`, etc. We then pass `app` as an argument to `functions.https.onRequest(app);`. That's it, you're done!

You can even add more paths if you wish, E.g. if we want an endpoint that accepts GET requests to an endpoint that looks like: `/widgets/foo/bar`, we simply add `app.get('/foo/bar', (req, res => { ... });`.

It's all taken directly from the [official Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps).
I'm surprised @Doug Stevenson didn't mention this in his answer.